# Attempting to find the next div element from the current one

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have html code like this:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 84px; bottom: auto; left: 5px; right: auto; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: none; max-height: none;" _afrc="2 1 8 1 start top">**CRED ID:** </div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 84px; bottom: auto; left: 115px; right: auto; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: none; max-height: none;" _afrc="3 1 8 1 start top">**11111972**</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 103px; bottom: auto; left: 5px; right: auto; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: none; max-height: none;" _afrc="2 1 10 1 start top">**CAQH ID:** </div>
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 103px; bottom: auto; left: 115px; right: auto; width: auto; height: auto; max-width: none; max-height: none;" _afrc="3 1 10 1 start top">**11189685**</div>
```

if something shows as two stars for you it is supposed to be bold.  I made the text bold so it shows up better.  Anyway I can use `//div[contains(text(),'CRED ID:')]` to get the div element containing "CRED ID".  The actual cred id value is "11111972".  I am wondering how, when I use the above xpath, I can tell it to get the text value of the next div (i.e., 11111972).  I can't really use a ../div because there are earlier and later divs at this level.  Can anyone suggest?

I could use a @FindBy and make a List, find the index if "CRED ID" and add 1 I suppose, but it seems like there should be another way?

Thanks

p.s. I never really understodd following-sibling but I do not know whether that would work here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis:

```
WebElement credId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'CRED ID:')]"));
WebElement credIdValue = credId.findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::div"));
```

Or, you can reach it in one go:

```
WebElement credIdValue = credId.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'CRED ID:')]/following-sibling::div"));
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think that would be more efficient or doing the @FindBy and making a list, and then looping through the list until I find the text, and us the next element?

Comment: @Tony I'd just get the element by xpath based on the text as proposed.